# Why is my implementation of array.sorted( by: ) in Swift returning a strange order?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have a custom class:

```
class MyClass: MySuperClass
{
    var myNumber: Int

    required init ( id: Int, myNumber: Int )
    {
        self.myNumber = myNumber
        super.init( id: id )
    }

    required init ( id: Int )
    { 
        fatalError( "init() has not been implemented" ) 
    }
}
```

I create an array of these objects of length 20:

```
var myNumbers: [ MyClass ] = []
```

I iterate through the array, printing out the values of myNumber:

```
0
1
1221
0
0
18394
0
0
0
0
0
1222
6
0
110
0
0
24
71
2
```

I then run a sort on them:

```
myNumbers.sorted( by: { $0.myNumber < $1.myNumber } )
```

And I iterate through the array a second time, printing out the values of myNumber:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
1
6
24
71
110
1222
1221
18394
```

As you can see it *sort of* sorts them, but not very satisfactorily.

What am I doing wrong please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A *self-contained* reproducible example would be helpful. – Note that `sorted( by:)` *returns* a new sorted array. `sort( by:)` sorts the array itself.

Comment: "'sort' has been renamed to 'sorted(by:)'"

Comment: My comment applies to Swift 3/Xcode 8. – Which version are you using?

Comment: What @MartinR said is correct. As of Swift 3.0, `Collection.sort()` sorts in place, while `Collection.sorted()` returns a new object. This is true for every `[word]()`/`[word]ed()` pair. The one with `-ed` returns a new object, while the one without applies the changes in place.

Comment: What I do not understand: If you use the "wrong" sorting method then the original array would not be modified at all, and not "almost sorted". That's why I asked for a reproducible example.

Comment: I may have to post a self-contained example, but I was hoping there would be a simple, obvious answer, because this is deeply entwined into an NDA-bound project. I'm on Swift 3, XCode 8.0, and if I do "sort( by: )" I get this buildtime error: "Extraneous argument label 'by:' in call" and if I delete "by:" I get this buildtime error: "'sort' has been renamed to 'sorted(by:)'"

Comment: Thanks @Martin-R. it is set to "No" and if I run "swift -version" in the Terminal I get "Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38)"

Comment: A minimal Swift 3 example: `var x = [3, 2, 1] ; x.sort(by: { $0 < $1 } ) ; print(x)` – You really should provide a [mcve], otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @Martin-R I just changed "= [ MyClass ]" to "= Array< MyClass >" and suddenly the buildtime errors are gone!

Comment: I think given the complexity of the project as a whole, a minimal complete and verifiable example would take hours to extrapolate. But I'll do it later if I have to.

Comment: I am at a loss as to why the sort was producing an odd result, but certainly using Array< MyObject > as opposed to [ MyObject ] has solved the buildtime problems, and then all the problems.

Comment: I just tested in `Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1)` targeting macOS, and using `[ MyClass ].sort(by:)` worked just fine. Maybe try updating, and see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: Thanks @thislooksfun, I'll update later and see how that goes.

Comment: I discovered in the end why the order was sort-of ordered: I was ordering on propertyA, but examining on propertyB. It was late at night, I was being stupid and don't mind admitting it.

Answer (score 1):

You want `.sortInPlace` I believe..

`myNumbers.sortInPlace( by: { $0.myNumber < $1.myNumber } )`

```
/// Sort `self` in-place according to `isOrderedBefore`.
///
/// The sorting algorithm is not stable (can change the relative order of
/// elements for which `isOrderedBefore` does not establish an order).
///
/// - Requires: `isOrderedBefore` is a
///   [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order#Strict_weak_orderings)
///   over the elements in `self`.
```